# ifelse() issue in grouping sequence of numbers (e.g. mm:ss type) into different vectors

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a sequence of data:

```
zz <- as.factor(outer(c(0, seq_len(23)), 
      seq(0, 45, 15), 
      function(x, y) paste0(sprintf("%02.f", x) , ":", sprintf("%02.f", y))))
```

I want to group the data in such a way:

```
if 00:00, 01:00, 02:00 .... then create a new vector x1 containing these
if 00:15, 01:15, 02:15 .... then create a new vector x2 containing these
if 00:30, 01:30, 02:30 .... then create a new vector x3 containing these
else if 00:45, 01:45, 02:45 .... then create a new vector x5 containing these
```

I tried ifelse() for that... but it was never ending code, almost.
Could there be a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option using `grep` can be as:

```
x1 <- grep(":00$",zz,value = TRUE)
x2 <- grep(":15$",zz,value = TRUE)
x3 <- grep(":30$",zz,value = TRUE)
x4 <- grep(":45$",zz,value = TRUE)
```

If your intention is to create a matrix with 4 columns with desired vectors then you can try as:

sapply(c(x1="00",x2="15",x3="30",x4="45"),
           function(x)grep(paste(":",x,"$",sep=""), zz, value = TRUE))

```
#          x1      x2      x3      x4     
# [1,] "00:00" "00:15" "00:30" "00:45"
# [2,] "01:00" "01:15" "01:30" "01:45"
# [3,] "02:00" "02:15" "02:30" "02:45"
# [4,] "03:00" "03:15" "03:30" "03:45"
# [5,] "04:00" "04:15" "04:30" "04:45"
# [6,] "05:00" "05:15" "05:30" "05:45"
# [7,] "06:00" "06:15" "06:30" "06:45"
# [8,] "07:00" "07:15" "07:30" "07:45"
# [9,] "08:00" "08:15" "08:30" "08:45"
# [10,] "09:00" "09:15" "09:30" "09:45"
# 
# so on
#
```

Comment: thanks, it works. and I rather liked sapply() approach. But one question, we col names are "00", "15".. etc. instead of x1,x2...

Comment: @I_m_LeMarque You can easily correct it. Have a look at updated answer.